# What is the type of a Swift Type?

Tags: swift

I want to pass an array of types to a function - but I'm not sure what is the type of a Swift Type.

Let's say I have two classes:
MyClass and AnotherClass.
I want an array like this [MyClass, AnotherClass].
What will be the type of the array?

Comment: In swift , all type must be same for creating an array like for such you can create an array of type Any , AnyObject , AnyClass

Answer (score 2):

If you need to contain only class types, `AnyClass` will works:

```
class MyClass {
    //...
}
class AnotherClass {
    //...
}
let classTypes: [AnyClass] = [MyClass.self, AnotherClass.self]
```

If you want to include some value types, you may need to use `Any` or `Any.Type`:

```
let types: [Any] = [Int.self, String.self, MyClass.self, AnotherClass.self]
let anyTypes: [Any.Type] = [Int.self, String.self, MyClass.self, AnotherClass.self]
```

But all three types, `AnyClass`, `Any` or `Any.Type`, are hard to use. You will soon find it is very hard just to instantiate a class in the array.

Answer (score 1):

It would be of `AnyClass` type which is base for all object types.

```
func checkClassTypes(types: [AnyClass]) {
  types.forEach { type in
    // Your custom classes don't necessarily have to subclass from NSObject.
    print(type is NSObject.Type)
  }
}

checkClassTypes([MyClass.self, AnotherClass.self])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question about Swift Types correctly, but Swift doesn't specify a Type as being a certain kind of variable. Swift defines that variables in code can have a certain type, which can be a float, a string, integer, etc. When it is said that Swift is type safe and infers a type, this means that Swift requires you to be clear on the type of values that you store in your variables (type safety) and that Swift will try to infer what type a variable is when you specify a value (type inference).

The type of your variable can also be more complex, like an enum, a struct or a class. Swift even sees an array or other collections as types. In this sense a Type could be defined as a piece of memory in which a constant or a variable (or a collection of these) is stored. A type can be different things. The great thing about having a Type as a constant/variable in which I store information, is that I can now defer the type of a variable until runtime, rather than that I have to specify it in my code. Or I can specify a structure of a generic type and later I can define different kinds of variables with the same structure, but of different types. Please, read for a more detailed understanding of dealing with types the Swift programming language from Apple. It is free and can be downloaded in the iBooks Store.

Now coming back to your second question of an array of [MyClass, AnotherClass] is kind of like deferring the types of your array until later. You can initially define your array as an array of AnyObjects or more swift-like AnyClass, like

```
myArray = [AnyClass]()
```

Later you can put different types of variables/objects in that array, like a Double, a String, or an object with a specific class.

You should be careful about building such an array, however. This array is not type safe and you haven't specified the type of object at a certain index. To prevent xcode having trouble with your code and your program from crashing, you should always type cast the individual objects in your array. For instance like

```
if let myObject = myArray[2] as? myClass { do something }
```

If you don't typecast your array both xcode and your program will do weird things.

I hope this answered your question.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing that you really want to create an array of *instances* of the two classes rather than an array of the class definitions.  If so, you will be creating an array of `Any` or `AnyObject`, not `AnyClass`.

```
class MyClass {
}

class OtherClass {
}

let m = MyClass()
let o = OtherClass()

let array1 = [m, o] as [Any]
// or
let array2 = [m, o] as [AnyObject]
```